# Comma-Separated String to Double C#

Tags: c#, double, string-parsing

I want convert 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 String to Double.

I tried `Convert.ToDouble(String);` and `Double.Parse(String);` but returned **1.0**

How to convert multi comma string to double?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You need to use a loop.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean? Do you want to return an array of doubles?

Comment: var p = new Participant(24, 320, 240, 
                    Environment.CurrentDirectory, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
                    6, 7,8,9,10,11,12); I need set multi comma double value

Comment: Do you need the result as a CSV (i.e.:1.0,2.0,3.0,etc.)?

Comment: That's not a string.. Maybe you just need to say `1.0, 2.0, ..`  (or `1d, 2d, .. `) instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of your question you actually have 10 numbers not 1.  Use this code:

```
var nums = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
var digits = nums.Split(',').Select(r => Convert.ToDouble(r)).ToArray();
// the result will be an array of doubles, also this only works with .NET 3.5 or better.
```

Let me know if this works for you.